# Can one hinge allow for a flat 180° without a gap and an offset at 90° (see drawing)?

Tags: hinges

[image: the closed and open position for a hinge]

I cannot visualize how a hinge can have two pieces of wood butted together with no gap *and* allow one piece to sit inside the other when at 90°

Note that the underside of the wood cannot have any protrusions, so the hinge cannot go there. Also, this is 1/4"|6mm boards, so I'm planning on gluing the hinge to the wood

This feels like a solved problem, but I don't know what to look for

Cheers

UPDATE: I'm going with Jasen's answer: making the planks themselves the hinge

[image]

Comment: panel hinges like used for kitchen cabinets can do this, but on on 1/4" boards, they need 3/4"  they use a complicated lever mechanism to achieve this.

Comment: LMGTFY: [euro hinge](https://www.google.com/search?q=euro%20hinge)

Comment: can you turn the boards into the hinge by making a square notched joint and pinning it?

Comment: The euro would not work because the board are only 1/4" thick.

Comment: @Jasen: you are the Answer! If you want credit, please submit as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You could go down to your local woodworking shop and ask for a *full overlay* hinge for thin materials. They should point you toward a beast like this:

[image]

Looks like this closed:

[image]

Picture courtesy of https://tddhardware.com/

Comment: It's a good answer, but 1/4" is 6mm, not 8mm

In my case, the box is only 60mm wide, so the hinges would take up most of the width, and that won't work for me

Comment: When close at 90^, it would have no gaps, but open to the 180^ position, there would be a gap.

Comment: @Programmer66, yes they are designed to move the door out of the way so as not to limit use of the full interior cabinet width.

Comment: @Richard Haven, yes the expanding post fasteners are for thicker material, but you said you wanted to **glue** it anyway so you would just forego using the supplied fastener system. I happen to be rather sceptical of the entire idea in any case, due to the constraints imposed by the design. @Jansen;s idea is lovely though...